# My canvas won't append

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I'm dealing with a not existing canvas element even though I created it. It just wont append to the body or some other element.

```
var el = document.getElementById("container");
var cv = document.createElement("canvas");
el.appendChild(cv);
document.body.appendChild(cv);
```

Comment: You can't append the same element in two places

Comment: I was just testing it, if I try to append it to one of them only it has the same result.

Comment: Have u tried creating a canvas with : var canvas = el.getContext("2d"); ?

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: See examples here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext

Comment: But I have no canvas to call this on.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cv = document.createElement("canvas");
console.log("If this exists it will return '<canvas></canvas>':", cv);
document.body.appendChild(cv);
var ctx = cv.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
```

Comment: And you are sure your browser supports the canvas element? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Your canvas element is appended to the container element.
Container element to the document body.

```js
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.setAttribute("id", "container");
var cv = document.createElement("canvas");

var ctx = cv.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
el.appendChild(cv);
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Same thing Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have a container element like
<div id="container"></div>

Comment: Yeah, I am positive

Comment: Could be because your element is not a part of the DOM yet

Comment: Just console var el = document.getElementById("container"); and see what it returns

Comment: logs null hm. This is my html: <div id="container"></div>